# Change a button color from being disabled grey to green

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have the following script and I want to be able to change the button colour from grey (when disabled) to green once enabled.

I have added both disabled and enabled property in my css and using vue.js (which I am new to) but so far it does not seem to go from grey to green. Rather it stays light green and then green.

Here is my script

CSS AND HTML

```
   .disabled {
opacity: 0.4;
background:grey;
}

.
.ctaBtn_Start,
.ctaBtn_Start a:link,
.ctaBtn_Start a:visited {
background: pink;

/*   VARIABLE   */
text-align: center;
border-radius: 0.625rem;
border: none;
font-size: 1.5rem;
font-weight: 700;
cursor: pointer;
/*vertical-align: middle;*/
color: #ffffff;
margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
vertical-align: auto;
}

.ctaBtn_Start:hover {
background: #00cc00;
/* VARIABLE */
}
.ctaBtn_Start:disabled,
button[disabled] {
background: yellow;
color: #ffffff;
}

.ctaBtn_Start:enabled,
button[enabled] {
background: #049804; // pink; // #006600;
// color: #049804;
}

 
// and HTML Button with vue.js binding to the css

<button   enabled disabled class="ctaBtn_Start"    
        type="submit"
        v-bind:class="{ 'disabled' : $v.$invalid || isLoading }">
    Start
</button>
```

Comment: Please append the current result, and if applicable, the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      invalid: true,
      isLoading: true
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.invalid = false
      this.isLoading = false
    }, 3000)
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```css
.disabled {
  opacity: 0.4;
  background:grey;
}

.
.ctaBtn_Start,
.ctaBtn_Start a:link,
.ctaBtn_Start a:visited {
  background: pink;

  /*   VARIABLE   */
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0.625rem;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*vertical-align: middle;*/
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  vertical-align: auto;
}

.ctaBtn_Start:hover {
  background: #00cc00;
/* VARIABLE */
}
.ctaBtn_Start:disabled,
button[disabled] {
  /*background: yellow;*/
  color: #ffffff;
}

.ctaBtn_Start:enabled,
button[enabled] {
  background: #049804; /* pink; // #006600;*/
  /*color: #049804;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <button :disabled="invalid && isLoading" :enabled="!invalid && !isLoading" class="ctaBtn_Start"    
          type="submit"
          v-bind:class="invalid || isLoading ? 'disabled' : ''">
      Start
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code. Without any explanation, people are more likely to copy and paste the code, without learning anything.

Comment: @ethry you are totally right mate, but I'm bad at explanation especially when is too little code to reproduce the problem, I'm just guessing.

Comment: If you can't explain the problem, at least explain your solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is make a method, for example `toggleColor()` and in the button you type: `<button @click="toggleColor"></button>`

In the function you write:

`toggleColor() {color === !color}`(toggling the color)

Then you write `if (color = true) {`set color to ...`}`

I hope this helped you out.